# Heart of the Swarm Leveling

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there an efficient and fast way to push my Race level in Heart of the swarm?

And does someone know how much time is needed to get every race to 30?

Comment: This is very speculative. Not sure if this sort of question is needed in gaming.SE

Comment: Maybe someone knows, because for the faq, gaming is the right Place (Game mechanics and terminology)

Comment: Except for its in beta with a limited access to the public. While this is being ever extended it is not an open beta. Besides, changed will be made and any "fast leveling" will not be applicable later on. This is a sure thing.

Comment: The question was perfectly valid, at least with opening the beta to all pre-orders, and had a simple answer. But the beta's over, the question should probably be removed. Or should I answer it anyway? :)

Comment: I'm very curious. Answer it ;) !

Comment: Duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/109358 and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/108777

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much XP is needed for each level?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/109358/how-much-xp-is-needed-for-each-level)

Comment: the other questions seem to be the duplicate D: mine is the oldest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most effective way to level is to always do games that gives you exactly 50k XP points since you only get a fraction of the total XP you should get once you pass the 50k XP in a game (you get 67% less IIRC).

You can also try to cheese your way through since when you finish a game extremely fast, you get bonus XP for the game length.

Other than that, it's all about how good you play. The better your macro becomes, the more units you'll be able to pump out and the more XP you'll get. The better your micro will be and the more XP you'll get for killing units.

This guy here explain pretty well how the game length bonus works: [What is the game length bonus?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/109244/what-is-the-game-length-bonus)

**XP charts for levels**
[image: XP charts for levels]

Answer (score 1):

At the lower levels, you will level faster. You get more points for longer games as more actions are done (making units, killing units etc...); the only way to improve your level is to play as much as possible, be it ranked or unranked. gl
It's taken me about 4 days to reach level 22 but I have played about 120 1v1 games.