# Is there any way to tell how much XP I've gained so far during a match?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Heart of the Swarm you gain XP for killing/building units in multi-player matches on Blizzard maps. My understanding is that there is a "soft cap" of 50,000xp per match; actions that give you XP give 100% of their value until you've reached 50kxp during a match, and then they only give 1/3 of their normal value for the rest of the match.

If your intent is to maximize the rate at which you gain XP, then it seems like you would want to have matches end right around when you hit the soft cap. Stopping before the soft cap wastes extra time on the period at the beginning of a match where XP gain is slow, and pushing well past the soft cap is of course getting you only 1/3 XP.

Is there any way to tell how much XP I've gained so far in a match, so I can decide whether to (for example), drag out a match against AIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've seen, there is no progress bar about that. But you can notice how much XP you get for basic stuff like building smoething and do it every 4-5 minutes until you notice the drop then quit the game or finish the AI.

I'm pretty sure that just playing games after games will get you more XP than trying to force XP into a match. Level 30 arrives pretty fast!

Comment: As a guy who grinded even level 5 in Beta, I have to agree: grinding, while easy to perform (mass Battlecruisers, mass Banelings, etc.) takes around 30 minutes per match and is a waste of one's life :) Also remember the [bonuses](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108506/33619).