# How much XP is needed for each level?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have started leveling my Starcraft 2 account in all 3 races, but I am wondering how much xp is needed for each level, and especially how much is needed in total to reach level 30 so I can get an idea of how long it will take me to get there?

I can see an increase in the amount of xp needed each level, but it looks at the moment as each level is decreasing how much more xp is needed.
[image: Screenshot of a level 3 Terran (37,953/85,000 XP); a level 4 Protoss (52,015/105,000 XP); and a level 6 Zerg (3,642/135,000 XP)]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Each race has 30 levels. The total amount of experience points required is *4,750,000*. And, as you noticed, the increase of points goes down as the levels get higher. The increases are as follows:

- *40k* starting at level 1
- *20k* starting at level 2
- *10k* starting at level 6
- *5k* starting at level 7
- *2.5k* starting at level 15

Rewards are earned at all levels except 1, 6, 12, 18, and 24. The following image ([credited to Existor on the Team Liquid forums](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=399876)) shows a breakdown of levels and rewards:

[image: Starcraft 2 rewards and level breakdown credit Existor from Team Liquid forums]